# SQL Server Management Studio - Multiple Object Explorer Windows

Tags: ssms

I'm currently building a database. The tables are all done and now I'm adding in my stored procedures. I'm also writing tests using tSQLt and Red Gate's SQL Test. Because of how this adds information to the database (each test is its own stored procedure, plus there are a large number of tSQLt stored procedures), I'm getting a very, very large number of stored procedures.

I'm finding that I'm scrolling up and down a lot in the Object Explorer window as I go back and forth between the list of tables (writing several tests for each table based upon its data structure) and the stored procedure list (when I need to create/update a stored procedure for a test that is failing).

I've already split out my Object Explorer and my SQL Test windows onto a separate monitor (Apple TV Airplay on a 55" TV FTW!), yet I'm finding that a little tweak could help me immensely.

Typically, I'm working in one range of my table list and one range of my stored procedure list, so that if I had two windows, I could set one to the relevant area of my table list and one to the relevant area of my sproc list, limiting or eliminating my scrolling.

Each time I try to select "Object Explorer" from the "View" menu, it simply highlights the currently-opened instance. Is there any way to get 2 of these? Is there any other workaround to get the same effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried running two instances of SSMS?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't accept this answer 4 years ago! This was the correct (albeit roundabout) way to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

another option here could be to have both Object Explorer and 
Object Explorer Details ( could be for different 
Server / DB if needed ) opened in separate windows

Answer (score 0):

You can open two management studio, scroll one for tables list and one for stored procedures list and resize both to fit your screen and your convenience. Weird, but that might be the only possible solution

Comment: Yeah, not something I'd really like to do, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Open multiple instances of SSMS and connect to different databases as you want. Or you can connect to the same DB in both instances and have tables list expanded in one and Stored procedures in second. I tried it myself with SSMS 2016